# Difference between *guile* and *beguile*?

Tags: word-usage

According to the dictionary, *guile* as a noun means cunning or deceit, while as a tr.verb it means to deceive. 
*Beguile*, doesn't seem to have a noun form, and as a tr.verb means to deceive or to be cunning. Is the difference simply that of a noun/verb?

Can guile be used as a verb? If I am sightseeing and a tout charges me too much, was I *guiled*? Or was I *beguiled*? (or neither?)(or both?)

Both seem to mean to deceive. Can anyone offer some clarification on the differences between the two? Are the interchangable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb form of [guile](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guile) is [rarely used](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=guiling,guiled,guile%20him,guile%20me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) nowadays. The noun form is still in popular use, but has shed most of its negative connotations of *dishonesty*, and has grown to imply the more positive attributes of "*artful deception or cunning*". The OED doesn't even bother to [list the now rare verb form](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/guile) and prefers the noun:

> he used all his *guile* and guts to free himself from the muddle he was in

The word [beguile](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beguile), on the other hand, is still used to convey trickery and deception. But, over time, its use has also been softened to carry an air of enchantment and allure. The [OED's entry for beguile](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/beguile) goes thusly:

> charm or enchant (someone), often in a deceptive way:
>
> *he beguiled the voters with his good looks*
>
> trick (someone) into doing something:
>
> *they were beguiled into signing a peace treaty*

So, it appears that the OP was *beguiled* into buying those trinkets ...

P.S. It's interesting to see how the [use of the phrase 'beguiling smile'](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beguiling%20smile&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) has increased over time.